# How to check if one Object partially contains another?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So i am trying to check if one object contains exactly another/ partial. For example, i want to check if `{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 2 }` contains `{ a: 1, b: 2 }`. But has to be in that order. If `a` is the first element and lines up, the `b` element will have to line up exactly afterwards. Plus is their anyway i could check there value? **Order does matter**.

```
//Here is my code currently:
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
    var array = [];
    var sourceNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(source);
  for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
         var collectionNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(collection[i])
        JSON.stringify(collectionNames).includes(JSON.stringify(sourceNames)) ?  array.push(collection[i]) : null
      }
      return array
}

whatIsInAName([{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 1 }, { a: 1, b: 2, c: 2 }], { a: 1, b: 2 });
```

Its a exact check but, only for the names. I wish it also compared the values.

It also isn't partially checking for the object in another. Like comaparing `{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 2 }` to contain `{ a: 1, b: 2 }`

Here was the challenge i was given  --> https://www.freecodecamp.org/challenges/wherefore-art-thou

Comment: There is no guarantee of order in a javascript object

Comment: ??? Your free to correct my code. Just anyway i can compare the too arrays?

Comment: Those aren't arrays, and they don't have an order, so you can't compare their order (that's charlie's point).

Comment: Those are not arrays. Those are objects. As said, they don’t have an order. You could try something like `[{a: 1}, {b: 2}, `…`]`, or a `Map`.

Comment: In addition to the external link to your code, please post the relevant code in your question.

Comment: OHHH okay. Ill fix my question.

Comment: I did, its that link.

Comment: But your demo has array of objects. Not clear what expected results are and please put all relevant code in the question itself. Demos are great but should only be used to support what exists in the self contained question

Comment: @Leed You've fixed the incorrect terminology, but your question is still nonsensical because (as two people have pointed out) objects don't have orders. Re: _"I did, it's that link"_, what freginold was requesting is that you place the code _in your question_.

Comment: Ill fix my code.  accidentally was trying to compare it like a array. I posted that link so people could go in and edit for themselves too see what they can do. So best way to compare a object without order??

Comment: Ok, so the actual question doesn't say anything about order (and you should have told us about the original question when you first posted your question). Here's how you can solve this: Step 1: figure out how to compare object A against object B to see if A contains all of the properties B has, with the same values. Step 2: Do this check for all items in the array, and only add the ones that succeed this check to the result array.

Comment: Yeah but i wont know the length of what i'm comparing. I could be comparing ```{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 2, d: 3 }``` against ```{a: 1} ```.  They are not going to be always number values either.

Comment: `Object.keys(obj)` returns an array of strings (property names) (that's one of the hints on the question's page). That array has a length. And the types of the properties are irrelevant as long as you can compare them to other properties using `===`.

Comment: If you (1) post your code here, *in your question*, and (2) tell us what results you're getting so far with your code (where it falls short or doesn't return what's expected) I think you'll get a lot more help.

Comment: Now i'm able to get a full array of of the object names, anything about the values?

Comment: _"anything about the values?"_ What? If you want help, _edit your question_ to show us where you are in terms of writing the code. I'm not going to guess what you've come up with and blindly give tips based on that.

Comment: please add the (wanted) result of the checking in the code.

Comment: Hint: You do not need to call `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` on `collection[i]`. You can go through `source`'s property names and check whether `collection[i]` has those properties and whether those properties have the same values as the ones in `source`. Also, get rid of that `JSON.stringify()` because that's not going to solve this.

Comment: so ```collection[i] === sourceNames ?  array.push(collection[i]) : null```?

Comment: @Leed No. First of all, stop using the conditional operator (`?:`) as a substitute for an `if` statement. That's not what it's for. Secondly, you need to check the properties one-by-one. It's not going to be as simple as `collection[i] === sourceNames` (which doesn't even make sense because `collection[i]` is an object and `sourceNames` is an array of strings).

Comment: a conditional operator i thought was like a if statement but in es6. I'm going off of what i'm being told by 3 different people.

Comment: @Leed The conditional operator has been around since before ES1. It's _like_ an if statement, but its purpose is to produce a value. For "if-this then do this, else do that", use an `if` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You coukd take the keys of the single object for comparing the values and use `every` for returning the result for filtering the array of objects.

- [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for getting parts of the array,
- [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) for getting an array with own keys of the object,
- Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for checking all keys and values,
- [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) for check if the key exist in the object,
- [Identity/strict equality operator `===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) for checking type and value of the operands.

```js
function compare(array, object) {
    return array.filter(function (o) {
        return Object.keys(object).every(function (k) {
            return k in o && object[k] === o[k];
        });
    });
}

console.log(compare([{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 1 }, { a: 1, b: 2, c: 2 }], { a: 1, b: 2 }));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks that does work. How does this code work though?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to guide you to figure out the problem on your own in the comments, but if you're just looking for a solution, here is how you can do this using basic JavaScript constructs (nothing fancy like `Array#filter` and `Array#every`).

It may be much longer than some other solutions, but it makes use of the basics of JavaScript:

```js
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
  var array = [];
  var sourceNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(source);
  
  // loop over each item in collection
  for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    var matchedProperties = 0;
    // loop over each property in source
    for (var j = 0; j < sourceNames.length; j++) {
      // check whether the property is in collection[i] and 
      // whether the value matches
      if (collection[i].hasOwnProperty(sourceNames[j]) && 
          source[sourceNames[j]] === collection[i][sourceNames[j]]) {
        matchedProperties += 1;
      }
      
      // add to array if all properties matched
      if (matchedProperties === sourceNames.length) {
        array.push(collection[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  
  return array
}


var result = whatIsInAName([{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 1 }, { a: 1, b: 2, c: 2 }], { a: 1, b: 2 });

console.log(result);
```